# Windows 10 Audio interruptions by disk access

Tags: windows-10

On a fresh and clean Windows 10 install with a secondary HDD Windows spins up the HDD 2-3 times per day at random times without any user interaction and certainly no access to files on that HDD.

This causes audio interruptions of around 1-2 seconds when playing back videos from YouTube or Netflix.

Indexing is deactivated for that Volume and Windows Search is disabled.

Is there a way to deactivate this without removing the HDD physically?

Comment: You need to figure out why it's spinning up, and why it's spinning up is related to your audio stutter issues.

Comment: I tried using resmon to determine whats causing the sinning up but this was very inconclusive. I see high disk usage for a short period of time but there is nothing in the list of services that sticks out. Windows Defender claimed to have made a scan at a matching time. I have excluded the volume from windows defender searches for now.